# Pandas: add new column based on category of another column and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df that has this structure:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cat', 'dog'],
                     'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]})
```

I have a dict that assigns categories like so:

```
    category_dict = {'red': ['color'],
 'blue': ['color'],
 'green': ['color'],
 'cat': ['animal'],
 'dog': ['animal']}
```

I want to use the dict to create another column with the categories:

```
data_update = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cat', 'dog'],
                     'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
                    'c': ['color', 'color', 'color', 'animal', 'animal']})
```

I thought `data['c'] = category_dict[data['a']]` would give my output, but instead I get the error `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Why are your values inside lists? Wouldn't it be easier to just keep them strings and use `map`?

Comment: Anyway, the answer to your question is `data.a.map(category_dict).str[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
flatten_dict = {k:v[0] for k,v in category_dict.items()}

data['c'] = data['a'].map(flatten_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`data['c'] = [category_dict[x][0] for x in list(data['a'])]`